# What is the prediction equation for penalized logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, prediction, regularization

I have used penalized logistic regression (R package `logistf`) to predict probability of a rare event. 0.12% is the event rate i.e., only 35 occurrence of event in the total 29k+ data points.

What is the prediction equation for penalized logistic regression? Is it same has logistic regression i.e., $\frac{\exp(a+bX)}{1 + \exp(a+bX)}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  The penalty only affects the optimal parameters.  Once the parameters are determined the structural form of the model is identical.

Comment: thanks Matthew. Additionally, is it possible to provide some link or reference materials that explains your answer in detail.

Comment: The primary source is freely available: https://stat.duke.edu/~scs/Courses/Stat376/Papers/GibbsFieldEst/BiasReductionMLE.pdf.  But, in general, penalty methods only change the form of the loss function being optimized, not the functional form of the model itself.